# obfuscator re-edit start/finish

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation

I am sorry if i made duplicate. 
So, i was at new tab on google chrome, popped up the developer tools [ as i do from time to time] and start reading anything it can show me...after a while i  was wondering about security and general meaning of public interpreted code stealthiness.

I'm not sure if i was clear in sentence above so ...
    lets say you have some js code [or any code] in server that has potentially [ unknowingly to any programer so far ] some bug in function. So... how to be sure that wont be the problem. Well you compress it, you obfuscate it and hope for the best. But then after the few months the new revision of the program is needed... but such code is mostly unreadable before unbfuscatiration and uncompression ... and that is a of of work and all comments and code-plan and algorithms are deleted

So does anyone has any solution for this? What is your practice ? Do you have original version saved somewhere else or ?

Comment: Normally, you would keep a copy of the original, unobfuscated code for yourself so you can edit it later, even if you only share an obfuscated version on the web.

Comment: so after uploading it again... you would obfuscate it again ? do you make it automatically [ via third program ] or you obfuscate it yourself ?